# ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher reported by pycharm.sh

Tags: python, ubuntu-11.04, pycharm

I have seen the following errors while I start to set the environment of pycharm.
Should I address those issues or it is ok to leave it.

Thank you

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads/pycharm-1.5.4/bin$ ./pycharm.sh 
[ 426143]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - 
Exit code 137 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:52)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessOutput.checkSuccess(ProcessOutput.java:89)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher.generateBuiltinSkeletons(PySkeletonRefresher.java:327)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher.regenerateSkeletons(PySkeletonRefresher.java:184)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher.regenerateSkeletons(PySkeletonRefresher.java:119)
    at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkType$5.run(PythonSdkType.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:423)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$4.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:575)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$6.run(ApplicationImpl.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:130)
[ 426189]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - PyCharm 1.5.4  Build #PY-107.576 
[ 426189]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - JDK: 1.6.0_27 
[ 426189]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
[ 426191]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. 
[ 426192]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - OS: Linux 
[ 426192]  ERROR - python.sdk.PySkeletonRefresher - Last Action: ShowSettings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please file a bug report in the [PyCharm issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/PY).